# Htop sorting CPU% column incorrectly

Tags: osx, sort, top, cpu-usage, htop

Sometimes when I'm trying to diagnose what process is hogging all of my laptop's resources, I notice that `htop` will sort the **CPU%** column incorrectly.

Example below:

[image: screen shot 2018-07-06 at 10 47 23 am]

The “CPU%” column is highlighted in the header row, so that means its sorting by that column (right?), yet it’s all out of order. It’s clearly not sorting it numerically, and neither is it sorting it lexicographically. I'm not sure how else it could be trying to sort it.

**Some Details:**

- Laptop: **MacBook Pro** (17-inch, Late 2011)
- OS: **El Capitan v10.11.6** (15G31)
- Htop Version: **htop 2.1.0**

Here's the content of my `~/.config/htop/htoprc` file.

```
# Beware! This file is rewritten by htop when settings are changed in the interface.
# The parser is also very primitive, and not human-friendly.
fields=0 48 17 18 38 39 2 46 47 49 1
sort_key=46
sort_direction=1
hide_threads=0
hide_kernel_threads=1
hide_userland_threads=0
shadow_other_users=0
show_thread_names=0
show_program_path=1
highlight_base_name=0
highlight_megabytes=1
highlight_threads=0
tree_view=0
header_margin=1
detailed_cpu_time=0
cpu_count_from_zero=0
update_process_names=0
account_guest_in_cpu_meter=0
color_scheme=6
delay=15
left_meters=AllCPUs Memory Swap
left_meter_modes=1 1 1
right_meters=Tasks LoadAverage Uptime
right_meter_modes=2 2 2
```

I wasn't able to find much on it after consulting with the Google Gods. Is this a known bug? Or is it perhaps a PEBKAC error? (I hope not, that would be embarrassing).

[Also posted at https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/810.]

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `~/.config/htop/htoprc`, that worked for me.

Comment: When suggesting that a file is deleted, you should explain why and what effects the user may expect to see.

Comment: I'll keep this Answer around for now, but note that the [github page](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/810.]#issuecomment-518386817) has a comment from Aug 5, 2019 indicating that deleting the htoprc file did *not* solve their particular problem. Please elaborate on what you thought was in your htoprc file that might have been problematic. Thank you!

Comment: I deleted that file following advice from an external source (github issue I believe?). I did see that comment, but having had the same problem I decided to give it a try given that it apparently gets re-written automatically (plus I hadn't customised htop extensively so wasn't afraid to lose critical config info). May be worth a try for vanilla htop users like myself :)

Answer (score 2):

For me reinstalling did not help, nor deleting htoprc.

I did figure out how to reproduce the problem, and a way to avoid it. Just wait for 5 cycles of the Update Interval (`delay` variable in htoprc). On the 5th refresh the problem goes away.

I've added this info to an open issue:

- https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/510

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. Once you use arrows to navigate, the list of processed is freezed for a defined period so sorting doesn't change the order of processes. It's described a later comment in the [linked issue](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/510#issuecomment-1126873842).

Answer (score 2):

I know its old question, but in case someone else finds no solution:

what i found is that when you click <kbd>F2</kbd> for Setup, choose `Display settings` on the left, then in the middle the first tick is `Tree view`.

Turn off Tree view, then processes wont be sorted by PID and sort by CPU will work properly.

[image]

Comment: 't' is the shortcut key to toggle Treeview on/off

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS with htop 2.0.1. Uninstalling then reinstalling htop fixed the problem. My config settings may have been messed up when I was changing settings within htop.